# Java Sockets - ArrayList loses information when I send over the connection

Tags: java, sockets

I am having an issue sending some data over a socket, everything works great until I try to send an class that contains:

```
int playerId  
int command   
int[] playerLocations
```

The data is received without any errors and command & playerID are retained fine. However the `int[]` is the right size but the values are always reset to 0 for some reason, and I cant see why. I have tried using an ArrayList also but the same problem occurs.

Server code for this part, the final for loop is the important part:

```
//now loop taking in turns
    while (true) {

        //first we get the player who's turn it is, and the corresponding thread for their client
        int playerTurn = game.getTurnNow();
        ClientThreadOnServer AciveClient = clientThreads.get(playerTurn);
        //then we send them a message saying it is their go
        try {
            AciveClient.out.writeObject(new TransferObject(playerTurn, 2, null));
            //we wait for them to click roll dice
            TransferObject reply = (TransferObject) AciveClient.in.readObject();
            //get the command back to roll the dice
            int command = reply.getCommand();
            int sender = reply.getPlayerId();
            // then make a move
            if (command == 2 && sender == game.getTurnNow()) {

                synchronized (this) { //synchronised to preven concurrent modification
                    System.out.println("command == 2");
                    game.rollDice();
                    game.takeGo();
                }
            }

            //then send the updated game information to everyone
            for (int i = 0; i < clientThreads.size(); i++) {
                synchronized (this) {

                    int[] playerLoc = game.getPlayers();
                    System.out.println("server says:" + playerLoc[i]);
                    clientThreads.get(i).out.writeObject(new TransferObject(i, 1, playerLoc));
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

where the system.out is "server says:" the correct value is printed, and when i debug the correct values can be seen in the variables section.

Here is the object being sent:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class TransferObject implements Serializable {

    private int playerId; //to be sent in forst data send to tell client which player they are
    private int turnNow; // ID of who's go it is now
    private int command; //0 = initialise, 1=game update, 2=roll, 3=end game
    private int[] playerLoc;

    public TransferObject(int playerId, int command, int[] playerLoc) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.command = command;
        this.playerLoc = playerLoc;
    }

    public int getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    public int getPlayerId() {
        return playerId;
    }

    public int getTurnNow() {
        return turnNow;
    }

    public int[] getPlayerLoc() {
        return playerLoc;
    }
}
```

and the client receiving section, command 1 is the bit that should print out the correct data but just prints "...on square 0"

```
 while (true) {
        try {
            int command = -1; //reset command to something not used in order to prevent confusion
            TransferObject transObj = (TransferObject) in.readObject();
            command = transObj.getCommand();
            if (command == 0) {//initialisation
                playerId = transObj.getPlayerId();

            } else if (command == 1) {//gui update
                for (int i = 0; i < transObj.getPlayerLoc().length; i++) {
                    //need to have gui stuff here eventually
                    System.out.println("Player " + i + " on square " + transObj.getPlayerLoc()[i]);
                }

            } else if (command == 2) {//ask for a roll
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Roll the dice?", "It's your go!", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                TransferObject objOut = new TransferObject(playerId, 2, null); //Send request for roll - NULL COULD BE AN ISSUE
                out.writeObject(objOut);

            } else if (command == 3) {//end game
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "Player " + transObj.getPlayerId() + " wins!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break; //exit loop and game ends
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data Transfer Error");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry there is so much code here, hopefully somebody can make sense of it. If you need any more info let me know.

Comment: That's strange. You are using standard Java serialisation, right? What does `java -version` print?

Comment: at first glance everything looks good. Try minimal problem: remove all code which doesn't touch int[] and then you'll have very small program which will contain problem, maybe some of your code clearing your table.

Comment: 1.6.0_21; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 17.0-b17. I will try to isolate the problem yes.

Comment: My only though would be that maybe primitive arrays aren't serialized?

Comment: @Nicholas I googled and they should be. I don't remember ever having had any problems serializing primitive arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the output stream code is serializing the TransferObject in another thread, and sees the player location array after it's been modified elsewhere in the server.

Try making a copy of the player location array before the final for loop in the server code, and passing the copy to the TransferObject constructor.

Copying the array will also ensure that all of the client threads see a consistent set of player locations.  With the synchronization shown above, the player locations could change between iterations of the final for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many things going on. You need to isolate and test individual portions to convince yourself that doesn't contain the problem. It seems to me the first thing to verify is the serialization of TransferObject.

You can use code this like to simply test the serialization/deserialization of your object

```
import java.io.*;

public static Object testSerialization(Object inObj)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

    oos.writeObject(inObj);

    // Ensure everything is written to the stream.
    oos.close();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais =
            new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

    return ois.readObject();
}
```

Use this method and some unit tests to prove it is okay.

I suspect the problem is in TransferObject. You are passing in a reference to an array in the constructor, and just hanging on to it. It is mutable, and if someone is messing with that array while you are serializing the TransferObject, bad things will happen. It seems to me that TransferObject should really be immutable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TransferObject implements Serializable {

    /** You should really have this for efficiency */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final int playerId; //to be sent in forst data send to tell client which player they are
    private final int turnNow; // ID of who's go it is now
    private final int command; //0 = initialise, 1=game update, 2=roll, 3=end game
    private final int[] playerLoc;

    public TransferObject(int playerId, int command, int[] playerLoc) {
        this.playerId = playerId;
        this.command = command;
        this.playerLoc = Arrays.copyOf(playerLoc, playerLoc.length);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Also: what is `/** You should really have this for efficiency */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;`

Comment: See Effective Java item #74. If you do not provide a private static final long serialVersionUID field for your class, the JVM will generate one for you at runtime by applying a complex procedure to the class. Also by specifying it explicitly yourself, you can control when the serialized form of the class has actually changed.